# a different version of interval scheduling

Tags: math

Given n intervals and a number k,give an algorithm to find the maxmium subsets of intervals such that no points is contained in more than k of them?
We know that when k = 1,this problem can be solved by a greedy algorithm.So I have been trying to develop a greedy algorithm for the above problem.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would approach this is to first get a set for all the bounds of all the intervals, and sort that set. This might be the set of at most n*2 point x_i. Then consider the sets S_i = [x_i,x_{i+1}]. Each of your starting intervals either contains the S_i or is disjoint. So for each S_i we can build a list T_i of the indices of all intervals which contain the set. So it intervals 1,2, 5 intersect the set S_1 than T_1 = {1,3,5}.

We now have a collection of sets T_i, and the problem reduces to finding the minimum set of indicies M so that  T_i union M has at most k elements for each T_i. We can simplify the problem somewhat by throwing away and T_i which starts with fewer than k items.

A recursive algorithm should be able to do a greedy search through the possible sets M.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer.That is a brilliant idea!But in the end I still have to check all the possible sets M and that takes a lot of time.